X1 Gen 12 Verizon 5G config
Has anyone been able to connect to Verizon 5G? I have a new X1 Gen 12 with Ubuntu 24.04.
I had WWAN settings for a bit but now the options seem gone from my network settings.
I have tried different nmcli add commands, do not know the proper settings to plug in.
